# Disable iOS from making a shipping tracking number clickable

Tags: html, ios

We have an app that sends a shipping confirmation email to customers. The tracking numbers are through Canada Post. Currently when viewing the tracking numbers in iOS, customers are allowed to click the tracking number and are redirected to USPS.

http://trackingshipment.apple.com/?Company=USPS&Locale=&TrackingNumber=CanadaPostTrackingNumber

Is there a way to prevent iOS from predicting the tracking number such as...

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Example HTML Div that is generated for the email.

```
    <div>
        <h4>Thank you for your recent purchase from Company.</h4>

        <p>Your order has been scanned and a tracking number is now ready.</p>

        <p>Your tracking number is as follows: "This is an unformatted string tracking number."</p>

        <p>If you would like to view the status of your order you can input the tracking number on this page <a href = 'http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber?execution=e2s1'>here.</a></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using a UIWebView or a UITextView? If it's a text view, there are settings in IB that tell it which types of things to make clickable. Choices are Links, Addresses, Phone Numbers, and Events. However, since you're showing HTML code, I'm guessing that you're using a web view.

Comment: @DuncanC Yeah the email is just generated with HTML. I have included the example DIV that holds the tracking number. Desktop and Android email clients just recognize the tracking number as text. iOS however confuses the Canada Post number with USPS and hence we get confused customers. I would just like to be able to disable the clickable link, however if it isn't possible, I may just have to format the tracking number with the proper link. It is just more of a pain doing that because the company ships through more than Canada Post.

Comment: `date=no` disables dates. Maybe `tracking=no` or `trackingnumber=no` will work.  You could potentially make it a link to the actual tracking site, giving customers the expected iOS behavior.

Comment: You could also try crudely splitting up the tracking number `<span>3242342</span><span>42342342</span>`

Comment: did you find any soluction

Comment: @HimeshGoswami negative on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` in the head of your HTML page.

If you have a telephone number that needs to be a link use `<a href="tel:TELEPHONENUMBER">TELEPHONENUMBER</a>`

Comment: As the title states, this is for shipping tracking numbers. Not telephone numbers. We ended up formatting the tracking numbers with the proper link. I would be interested in knowing if there is a proper way to disable this feature though.